# How to change the date format in javascript for existing date

Tags: javascript

I have downloaded a war file (not my code) websockets application for live chat(Java Application)

And this is the information i am receiving from back end (for which i don't have code)

```
Object {message: "as", sender: "sdas", received: "Thu Nov 19 21:12:36 IST 2015"}
```

Is it possible to change the date so that i can get only

`Thu Nov 19 21:12:36` , instead of **Thu Nov 19 21:12:36 IST 2015**

```
function onMessageReceived(evt) {

    var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data); 
    console.log(msg);
    var $messageLine = $('<tr><td class="received">' + msg.received
            + '</td><td class="user label label-info">' + msg.sender
            + '</td><td class="message badge">' + msg.message
            + '</td></tr>');
    $chatWindow.append($messageLine);
}
```

Could you please let me know how to do this

Comment: Is the `received` a String or a Date? If Date you can easily change it, if String you can either parse it to however you need or convert to Date and change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any way you are getting valid long date lets remove tailing two words of the string,

```
function simpleDateString(dt){       

    return dt.split(" ").splice(0, 4).join(" ");
}
```

use the above funtion to remove tailing words, 
lets modify your function

```
function onMessageReceived(evt) {

    var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data); 
    console.log(msg);
    var simpleDate = simpleDateString(msg.received); //parse your date string
    var $messageLine = $('<tr><td class="received">' + simpleDate 
            + '</td><td class="user label label-info">' + msg.sender
            + '</td><td class="message badge">' + msg.message
            + '</td></tr>');
    $chatWindow.append($messageLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to get everything before the time:

```
function onMessageReceived(evt) {
    var msg = JSON.parse(evt.data); 
    var date=msg.received.match(/(.*\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/);
    var $messageLine = $('<tr><td class="received">' + date[1]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Date`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

to automatically parse and create pretty much any format you want.

In addition, since it looks like your format is static, you can use simply string manipulation functions to extract only the main date (less versatile and generally less recommended, but more efficient and legacy-compatible).